# Enum assignment rendering unwanted HTML (Phoenix)

Tags: templates, elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a Phoenix template in which I dynamically generate 50 random square divs through the server, each with their own colors and sizes.  To do this, I run a loop, assign a random number from 1-100, and perform operations on that number.

I could simply assign random classes inline with something like `<div class="<%=Enum.random(['class-1','class-2'...]) %>"` but let's assume I want to reference an outside variable.

My template code looks like this:

```
<section id="my-section">
  <%= for x <- 1..50 do %>
    <%= myrandom = Enum.random(1..100)

        colorClass = cond do
          myrandom < 2 ->
            "color-red"
          myrandom < 10 ->
            "color-orange"
          myrandom < 25 ->
            "color-yellow"
          myrandom < 50 ->
            "color-green"
          true ->
            "color-blue"
        end 

        sizeClass = cond do
          rem(myrandom, 5) == 0 ->
            "size-1"
          rem(myrandom, 5) == 1 ->
            "size-2"
          rem(myrandom, 5) == 2 ->
            "size-3"
          rem(myrandom, 5) == 3 ->
            "size-4"
          rem(myrandom, 5) == 4 ->
            "size-5"
        end
    %>
    <div class="square <%=colorClass %> <%=sizeClass %>"></div>
  <% end %>   
</section>
```

The resulting HTML looks like this:

```
<section id="my-section">
    size-3
    <div class="square color-yellow size-3"></div>
    size-2
    <div class="square color-blue size-2"></div>
    size-3
    <div class="square color-blue size-3"></div>
    size-4
    <div class="square color-blue size-4"></div>
    ...
```

Somehow the `sizeClass` variable is being rendered inline before the `div` gets generated.  How can I do this without the side effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you're using `<%=` around the large code block, which inserts the value returned by the code block into the HTML, and your code block returns the value of the last expression, which is the value assigned to `sizeClass`. You can fix it by changing `<%=` to `<%`:

```
<%
  myrandom = Enum.random(1..100)

  colorClass = ...

  sizeClass = ...
%>
```

---

Also, you can rewrite the `sizeClass` assignment to just this:

```
sizeClass = "size-#{rem(myrandom, 5) + 1}"
```

And you probably know it already, but it's recommended to put such large code blocks into views instead of in the template. You might want to move this code into a function in your view.

Comment: Works well.  For some reason I still need the `=` in `  <%= for x <- 1..50 do %>`...why is that?

Comment: That's because you _do_ want to insert the HTML produced inside `for` into the page. Without that, the return value of the `for`, which is the HTML inside the `for`, will be ignored.